# Sequelize: Limit AND Order Eagerly Loaded Associations

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have 4 tables.  Users, Rooms, Messages, and a join table RoomUsers.

```
I want to write a query that:
 1. Return a list of rooms
 2. Each room with the last message sent
 3. Rooms ordered by the message last sent
```

**The problem** is that I'm unable to **concurrently** limit eagerly loaded nested associations **AND** order by nested associations.

```
Users.hasMany(Messages) / Message.belongsTo(Users)
Rooms.hasMany(Messages) / Message.belongsTo(Rooms)

RoomUser.belongsTo(Users) / Users.belongsToMany(Rooms, {through: RoomUsers})
RoomUser.belongsTo(Rooms) / Rooms.belongsToMany(Users, {through: RoomUsers})
```

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using migrations vs. Sequelize's coded associations (aka `User.hasMany(Messages)`)

My code for my models/migrations can be found here: https://github.com/Derrick-Mei/nodeChat/tree/master/database (note, I made some casing changes for readability in the example below)

**What I've Tried**

***Querying the Rooms table***

```
await Room.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Message,
      limit: 1, // YOU CAN LIMIT
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  order: [["messages", "id", "DESC"]], // OR YOU CAN ORDER, BUT NOT BOTH
});
```

When I try to limit the nested association (messages), AND order rooms by last message, I get an error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "room"."id", "room"."name" FROM "rooms" AS "room" ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC;
(node:23360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "messages"
```

I've tried varying attributes such as, `subQuery: false`, `through: {}`, `required: true`.  Nothing is working so far.

Attempts to query the join table results in the same limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Sequelize.literal().using this we can access messages.id easily and get the result.

```
return await Room.findAll({ 
include: [
    {
      model: Message,
      offset:0,
      limit: 1, // YOU CAN LIMIT
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
 order: [[Sequelize.literal(`messages.id`), `DESC`]],
 subQuery:false
});
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  I am still getting the same error message as I posted above.  Both your code and my code will work without the limit, but as soon as I add the limit, I get the posted error message.  I think it's an issue with the combination of both LIMIT and ORDER in Sequelize.

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4446

Can you please open link and check in this link you will find duplicating:false in include.

Comment: I just tried that flag and unfortunately it does not work.  I am still getting the same error message when trying to do both LIMIT and ORDER.  I looked online and I think the issue might be related to the many-to-many relation (room to users).